# How can I find members

Tags: civimember, database

I would like to know if it is possible to find a person on the database only with the CIVI number, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

You can also just click in the search bar at the left of the Civi menu and select "Contact ID".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to find contact using CiviCRM Id. You can use advance search (CiviCRM >> Find >> Advance Search). Use Contact ID field to use it as a filter.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep